# How to Push a cloned TFS project to Git

Tags: git, tfs

I've a project cloned from TFS, using GIT-TF. Successfully cloned it to my local system. But the problem now is I'm not able to push it to GIT.
So, my question is, the project I've cloned is already a git repository or I've to initialize it?

And please explain the process step by step to push cloned project to GIT.

Comment: What do you mean "push it to git"? You already *have* a git repository. `git-tf` clones *from* TF *to* a new git repository. Do you mean how to push to some other repository?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , thanks for confirming that cloned project is already a git repository.
"push it to git" means, I want to push it to a remote GIT repository now. So what are the steps?

Comment: What's the problem when you try to push it to remote GIT?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a Git tutorial. There are several good ones. SO is a Q&A site, so it isn't suitable for tutorials that may take several pages. What you are looking for is how to add a new remote using whatever client you want (command line, TortoiseGit, SourceTree, whatever) and then pushing to it

Answer (score 0):

You could push the project to remote Git via following command:

```
git remote add <name> <your remote Git repository url>
git push <the name you specified in last command>
```

Comment: I've 4 folders which I've cloned into a Master folder(created master folder manually).like
- Master  
    - Folder1  
    - Folder2  
    - Folder3  
     - Folder4  
So, now I want to push these 4 folders to remote repo with same hierarchy, like these 4 folders should be inside master branch in remote repo.
What should be the steps?

Comment: So these 4 folders are cloned to Master folder one by one?

Comment: Yes, @Eddie .  And now when I push *Folder1* , contents of this folder are being pushed to remote *Master* branch , not the folder itself. :(

Comment: So you actually have 4 repositories in Master folder now. However, you can refer to this article for how to merge these repositories to one: http://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/